# I have a problem solving a system of equations. The problem is that I don't know how to continue the process.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, roots, quadratics, radicals

I need help with a problem based on system of equations:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
-1=(-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac})/2a \\ 
3=(-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac})/2a \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I tried to solve it and I arrived here:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a=-b/2 \\ 
\sqrt{b^2+2bc}=-2b \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

then, I don't know how to continue to solve it, I tried to square both sides but It seems that it doesn't give the exact result.

Answer (score 2):

note that what you have is:
$$\alpha=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=-1$$
$$\beta=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=3$$
and we know that the quadratic formula, solving the general equation:
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$
is given as:
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
so we can also say that:
$$f(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=0$$
$$(x+1)(x-3)=0$$
$$x^2-2x-3=0$$
so:

$a=1$, $b=-2$ and $c=-3$

Comment: While I like the elegance of this approach, you found not all solutions. If you scale $a$, $b$ and $c$ with a common non-zero factor, this will give you another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ and $x_2=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$

Thus, $$x_1+x_2=2$$ and $$x_1x_2=-3,$$
which says that $x_1$ and $x_2$ they are roots of the eqation
$$x^2-2x-3=0$$ and also
$$ax^2+bx+c=0,$$ where $a\neq0$ by the given.

Finally, $b=-2a$ and $c=-3a$.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the two equations, we get $$\frac{-b}{a}=2.$$
Multiplying the two equations, we get $$\frac{c}{a}=-3.$$
So for any non-zero $a$, we have $b=-2a$ and $c=-3a$.

Comment: Adding the two equations and multiplying them? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @NormanFacco it is exactly what everyone else has done. There are two equations, when you add them, the square root terms cancel out and you are left with only $-b/a$ on one side and $3-1=2$ on the other side. Now start again and multiply the two equations.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you were asked to find expressions for $b,c$ in $a$ (or something like that) under the condition that the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has $-1$ and $3$ as roots.

If so then realize that: $$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-3)(x+1)=ax^2-2ax-3a$$telling you that $b=-2a$ and $c=-3a$.

Found is actually that: $$b:c:a=(-2):(-3):1$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just two things I want to ask: 1) so a can be also, for example, 2? 2) b:c:a what does it mean?

Comment: If you must solve $(a,b,c)$ then there are the possibilities $(a,-2a,-3a)$ where $a\neq0$. So indeed you can have $a=2$. $b:c:a$ is a notation concerning the ratios. Unessential. The equality just says here: if $a=1$ then $b=-2$ and $c=-3$.

Comment: You helped me a lot! New things learnt today! :)

Comment: You are welcome.